# Nginx not proxying Next.js correctly

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js

I have nginx directly installed on my server, with a proxy to a Docker container containing a Next.js application.

The HTML of the Next.js is being loaded correctly, but all the assets are failing:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;

    server_name app.mydomain.ml;

    include extras.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.ml/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.ml/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_read_timeout 240s;
   }
}
```

It looks like nginx is trying to open the JS files instead of passing them to the proxy. The files are inside a container. I have a similar setup which works fine on another instance.

Below are part of the nginx error log:

```
2020/06/24 19:39:50 [error] 11172#11172: *482 open() "/etc/nginx/html/_next/static/chunks/75fc9c18.5b5b04c7a1a3ce1f0adc.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: app.mydomain.ml, request: "GET /_next/static/chunks/75fc9c18.5b5b04c7a1a3ce1f0adc.js HTTP/2.0", host: "cfcdemo.ml", referrer: "https://app.mydomain.ml/"

2020/06/24 19:39:50 [error] 11172#11172: *482 open() "/etc/nginx/html/_next/static/chunks/22b3a38a.fdf56032c38364c88402.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx, server: app.mydomain.ml, request: "GET /_next/static/chunks/22b3a38a.fdf56032c38364c88402.js HTTP/2.0", host: "cfcdemo.ml", referrer: "https://app.mydomain.ml/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed all the crap in the location block but the proxy_pass and suddenly worked.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}
```

Comment: Marked answer as useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a alias for this

```
   location /_next {
                alias "/etc/nginx/html/_next/;
        }
```

Comment: Because my Next.js app is inside a Docker container.